# Definition of android device natural orientation

Tags: android, orientation, device

I want to change the basic orientation of an android device. Curently its startup orientation is landscape, I need portrait.
I managed to modify the acceleration values so that the axis now point to where I want them to point to.
But the device seems to have its own definition of up and right. Now I have to change this.

Can someone tell me where this can be done? I guess there is a config file out there that I can't identify.

There are millions of hits searching for this problems. Unfortunately they all deal with java programming, not with OS code.

Comment: To make it even more clear: I am building my own Android OS. I need to change the system's definition of where is "up side" and make the desktop screen appear in another orientation. It is NOT app related!

Comment: Let me explain this more precisely. Imagine the device is laying flat on the table, then switched on. There is no information about being in landscape or portrait mode. However the device knows it shall be in smartphone mode or tablet mode.
What I need is a way to tell the device: you are a smartphone, not a tablet! So please behave like you were portrait unless you are clearly tilted.

Comment: really noone knows something about that? Do you need more information? The question has not been answered although there are two replies.

Answer (score 1):

In your **manifest** file under **activity** tag that is on which screen you want to apply that orientation.

For ***portrait***

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

For ***landscape***

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but it is about OS things, not apps!

Comment: You mean you need to change the orientation of device and not app, because the above answer is related with app orientation

Comment: yes this is exactly what I want to do but I don't know how :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines of code in Androidmanifest.xml for the orientation

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```